# How do i link an old excel file sheets to the current file using a macro. I have the code but im facing an error

Tags: excel, vba

This file has existing sheets such as Form, Quote etc. This macro will link the old existing file which has the data in its sheets ( Form, Quote ).Over here, it is written as the file will open the source file, move the sheets to the new one, delete and rename. but im facing an error. In a folder, there will only be two files with the extension xlsm, and open that.
Im facing an error here   **s.Sheets("Form").Move Before:=wb.Sheets("Form")**

```
Sub connect(control As IRibbonControl)

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim s As Workbook
Dim relativePath As String
Dim Str As String
Dim Oval As String
Dim Str1 As String
Dim Oval1 As String

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
sDir = GetWorkbookPath(wb)
Dim fso As Object, Folder As Object, file As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Folder = fso.GetFolder(sDir)
For Each file In Folder.Files
        If Right(file, 5) = ".xlsm" Then
        Z = Z + 1
        End If
        Next file
If Z > 3 Then
MsgBox ("There are more than 2 excel files in the PVCME folder, please only keep the latest quote file in the folder.")
End
End If

For Each file In Folder.Files
        If Right(file, 5) = ".xlsm" Then
        Set s = Workbooks.Open(file, ReadOnly:=False)
        **s.Sheets("Form").Move Before:=wb.Sheets("Form")**
        s.Sheets("Quote").Move After:=wb.Sheets("Quote")
        s.Sheets("Non-FF2 Costing").Move After:=wb.Sheets("Non-FF2 Costing")
        s.Sheets("Costing Sheet").Move After:=wb.Sheets("Costing Sheet")
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wb.Sheets("Form").Delete
        wb.Sheets("Quote").Delete
        wb.Sheets("Non-FF2 Costing").Delete
        wb.Sheets("Costing Sheet").Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        wb.Worksheets("Form (2)").Name = "Form"
        wb.Worksheets("Quote (2)").Name = "Quote"
        wb.Worksheets("Non-FF2 Costing (2)").Name = "Non-FF2 Costing"
        wb.Worksheets("Costing Sheet (2)").Name = "Costing Sheet"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wb.Worksheets("Form").Range("G5").formula = "=VLOOKUP(C5,Dropdown!AF2:AG5,2,FALSE)"
        
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("L2").formula = "=ROUNDUP(Quote!I21,0)"
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("L3").formula = "=XLOOKUP(G6,Dropdown!$Z$3:$Z$9,Dropdown!$AA$3:$AA$9)"
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("L4").formula = "=IF(Form!C14=""IND"",""Industrial"",""Natural Gas"")"
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("L5").formula = "='Costing Sheet'!F2"
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("C4").formula = "=IF(Form!C21="""","""",Form!C21)"
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("C6").formula = "=IF(Form!C22="""","""",Form!C22)"
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("C8").formula = "=IF(Form!F21="""","""",Form!F21)"
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("C10").formula = "=IF(Form!F9="""","""",Form!F9)"
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("C12").formula = "=IF(Form!F10="""","""",Form!F10)"
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("C14").formula = "=IF(Form!F13="""","""",Form!F13)"
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("C16").formula = "=IF(Form!F12="""","""",Form!F12)"
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("C18").formula = "=IF(Form!C23="""","""",Form!C23)"
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("C20").formula = "=IF(Form!C17="""","""",Form!C17)"
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("C23").formula = "=IF(Form!F25="""","""",Form!F25)"
        Str = "Total GP after Commission (%)"
Set pfind = wb.Worksheets("Costing Sheet").Range("A:D").Find(What:=Str, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
Oval = pfind.Offset(0, 1).Value
Str1 = "Total Commission"
Set pfind = wb.Worksheets("Costing Sheet").Range("A:D").Find(What:=Str1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
Oval1 = pfind.Offset(0, 1).Value
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("C25").Value = Oval
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("C27").formula = "=Quote!I21 & "" "" & $L$3"
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("C29").formula = "=IF(Form!C24="""","""",Form!C24)"
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("G4").formula = "=IF(Form!F6="""","""",Form!F6)"
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("G6").formula = "=IF(Form!F14="""","""",Form!F14)"
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("G8").formula = "=IF(Form!C13="""","""",Form!C13)"
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("G10").formula = "=IF(Form!C12="""","""",Form!C12)"
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("G12").formula = "=IF(Form!C14="""","""",Form!C14)"
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("G14").formula = "=IF(Form!F22="""","""",Form!F22)"
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("G16").formula = "=IF(Form!F7="""","""",Form!F7)"
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("G18").formula = "=IF(Form!F23="""","""",Form!F23)"
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("G23").formula = "=IF(Form!C26="""","""",Form!C26)"
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("G25").formula = "=IF(Form!C25="""","""",Form!C25)"
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("G27").formula = Oval1
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("G29").formula = "=IF(Form!F24="""","""",Form!F24)"
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("G20:H20").ClearContents
        wb.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("G21:H21").ClearContents
        wb.Worksheets("OE Sales order checklist").Range("B6").formula = "=Quote!I21"
        wb.Worksheets("OE Sales order checklist").Range("B7").formula = "=Form!F14"
        wb.Worksheets("OE Sales order checklist").Range("B8").formula = "=Form!F13"
        wb.Worksheets("OE Sales order checklist").Range("B9").formula = "=Form!C5"
        wb.Worksheets("OE Sales order checklist").Range("B10").formula = "='Order Entry Form'!G23:H23"
        wb.Worksheets("OE Sales order checklist").Range("I4").formula = "=Form!F23"
        wb.Worksheets("OE Sales order checklist").Range("I6").formula = "=Form!C9"
        wb.Worksheets("OE Sales order checklist").Range("I7").formula = "=Form!F9"
        wb.Worksheets("OE Sales order checklist").Range("I8").formula = "=Form!F10"
        wb.Worksheets("OE Sales order checklist").Range("I10").formula = "=Form!F25"
        wb.Worksheets("OE Sales order checklist").Range("I11").formula = "=Form!F6"
        wb.Worksheets("OE Sales order checklist").Range("I12").formula = "='Order Entry Form'!G27"
        
        wb.Worksheets("Buyer Checklist").Range("C4").formula = "='OE Sales order checklist'!B5"
        wb.Worksheets("Buyer Checklist").Range("C5").formula = "='Order Entry Form'!C27:D27"
        wb.Worksheets("Buyer Checklist").Range("C6").formula = "='Order Entry Form'!C14:D14"
        wb.Worksheets("Buyer Checklist").Range("C7").formula = "=Form!C5"
        wb.Worksheets("Buyer Checklist").Range("C8").formula = "='OE Sales order checklist'!B11"
        wb.Worksheets("Buyer Checklist").Range("L4").formula = "='OE Sales order checklist'!I4"
        wb.Worksheets("Buyer Checklist").Range("L5").formula = "=Form!C9"
        wb.Worksheets("Buyer Checklist").Range("L6").formula = "='Order Entry Form'!C10:D10&""/""&'Order Entry Form'!C12:D12"
        wb.Worksheets("Buyer Checklist").Range("L7").formula = "='Order Entry Form'!G23:H23"
        wb.Worksheets("Buyer Checklist").Range("L8").formula = "='Order Entry Form'!C4:D4"
        wb.Worksheets("Buyer Checklist").Range("R12").formula = "='OE Sales order checklist'!B12"
        wb.Worksheets("Buyer Checklist").Range("R13").formula = "='OE Sales order checklist'!B14"
        wb.Worksheets("Buyer Checklist").Range("R14").formula = "='OE Sales order checklist'!B13"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        s.Close SaveChanges:=False
        myFileName = wb.Sheets("Form").Range("C9").Value & "Order rev"
        relativePath = sDir & Application.PathSeparator & myFileName
wb.SaveAs fileName:=relativePath
Kill sDir & "\Technical & Commercial Proposal Tool.xlsm"
        End If
        Next file



End Sub
```

Comment: @BigBen, When I move the sheets, wont it be like Quote (2).
I have also changed the name but doesnt work

Comment: You need to explain the specific error message you're getting.

Comment: Run time error 9:
Subscript out of range

Comment: On which line do you get that error?

Comment: Then either `s` or `wb` or both have no sheet named Form. Check for leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: @BigBen -> Checked there are no spaces, names are correct

Comment: Then `s` or `wb` are not what you think they are.